# AWS S3 [curl] Error 56: Chunked-Encoded data

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, xml-parsing, amazon-s3

I am trying out Amazon S3's PHP SDK and always get this error no matter what function I try:

```
[curl] 56: Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data Error
```

I've read S3 doesn't use chunked-encoded data and can't seem to find more AWS issues about this anywhere else. Of the few which seemed related the most common solution I've read is to use HTTP 1.0. I've tried adding this code to the factory parameters:

```
'curl.options' => array('CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION'=>'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0')
```

After adding the above line I no longer get the chunked-encoded error but instead get another one:

```
Unable to parse response body into XML: String could not be parsed as XMLHTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Looking at the XML response it seemed to be formatted ok but at the end of it an extra character always shows up. Where it came from I don't know. Could that be the reason why I get an XML parse error?

Any idea where the problem really is? I am using WAMP with Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) and PHP/5.4.12 and the latest AWS SDK version.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything sitting between you and S3? A proxy server, maybe?

Comment: Nope. I don't think so.

Comment: Using WAMP 32bit seemed to have solved this issue and AWS functions seems to be working now. No hack needed. But then I'd like to find out why it keeps on getting those errors when using WAMP 64 bit.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find a fix for it? Thanks.

Comment: Jonathan, I was getting tired trying to find solutions for it for WAMP 64bit so I tried WAMP's 32 bit version instead and it worked with no hack needed. I had no problems running it on my MAMP setup either.